# Typescript two object union - problem with making typescript think it's the other type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I encountered a really weird problem and I'm not sure if the problem is related to badly written types or it's a weird typescript thing.

So I have this props type:

```
type SelectAnswersProps = (
  | {
      onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<MultiSelectAnswerOptionsType | null>>;
      value: MultiSelectAnswerOptionsType;
      isMultiSelect: true;
    }
  | {
      onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction<SelectAnswerOptionsType | null>>;
      value: SelectAnswerOptionsType;
      isMultiSelect: false;
    }
) & {
  displayMode?: SelectAnswerOptionsType['displayMode'];
  disabled?: boolean;
};
```

And then I'm trying to force typescript to read what type is being passed to `onChange` method.

```
if (isMultiSelect) {
      onChange({
        answers,
        isHeadless,
      });
    } else {
      onChange({
        answers,
        displayMode,
      });
    }
```

So the first onChange is correct as it shows its type as `onChange: (value: SetStateAction<MultiSelectAnswerOptionsType>) => void` but the second one I'd expect to be like in the types specified in props with `isMultiSelect` being `false` but instead type of 2nd onChange is as follows:
`onChange: (value: SetStateAction<MultiSelectAnswerOptionsType> & SetStateAction<SelectAnswerOptionsType>) => void` so kinda mix of both even though from props types you would say it's either one or another.

I reckon I've done something silly here.
Really appreciate all your help.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. There should be no pseudocode, typos, undeclared or unimported types or values, missing syntax, etc.

Comment: I tried creating a similar example and I couldn't reproduce this tbh :/

Comment: @jcalz @darthgoldstein Please find the reproduction here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-error-v765np?file=/src/index.tsx
Weirdly there's another error on line 64, although on my local machine (VS Code) it's able to figure out that if isMultiline is set to true then the type I'm working on is `MultiSelectAnswerOptionsType`

Comment: A [mre] should be plain text in the question itself.  A link to a web IDE is a nice supplement, but it's not sufficient.   Also note that a [mre] should have a minimum of code; you should strip it down to the least amount of code that demonstrates your issue, which presumably would be some small destructured discriminated union like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKy2MN)

Comment: Is your code dependent on an old version of TypeScript?  If I put your code into TS4.7 [it looks fine to me](//tsplay.dev/w1PVYW), presumably because [destructured discriminated unions](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions) was added in TS4.6.  Does this fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer but I'd really hope you could minimize the code example to a self-contained reproducible plaintext version first.

Comment: @jcalz you're spot on I'm on 4.3.4... I was trying to switch the version on codesandbox but it didn't pick that up... I'm not very good with this tool probably needed a full reboot of the container. Thank you very much! I'm not sure if I'll find time to tweak that code example tho, most likely over the weekend if that helps.

Comment: Let me know and I'll take another look then.  Good luck

Comment: Hello Ptak. In my opinion, the problem is the architecture. 
You have to try to resolve with Generics, and an architecture who allows you decided what kind of object do you want to use, withot forcing type.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `props` to be *(simplified for readability)*:

```
props: { onChange: MultiSelectDispatcher, ... } | { onChange: SelectDispatcher, ... }
```

That means, the `props` can only be the one or the other, and
Typescript doesn't know which one it is, and infers that from the usage:

```
if( isMultiSelect ){
  onChange({ answers, isHeadless }); // <-- TS thinks: probably the "MultiSelect" one
} else {
  onChange({ answers, displayMode });  // <-- TS already decided "MultiSelect" earlier
}
```

So Typescript decides which type the whole `props` object probably is at some point, **and sticks to that decision** from there on.

### Use a type guard *(maybe)*

As a solution you ***might*** be able to use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) *(maybe not this easy, see the "But ..." below)*, like:

```
const guardMultiSelectProps = ( theProps: unknown ): theProps is MultiSelectProps => {
    return theProps.isMultiSelect; 
}

if( guardMultiSelectProps( theProps ) ){
  onChange({ answers, isHeadless }); // <-- TS thiks: probably the "MultiSelect" one
} else {
  onChange({ answers, displayMode });  // <-- TS already decided "MultiSelect" earlier
}
```

But also Typescript might have inferred the type of the props even earlier,
or will "suddenly" do that if you make some changes to your code later.

### Define the type of onChange (if possible)

I suggest, if possible, not to define two alternatives for the `props` object, but instead define only one type for the `props`, with two alternative `onChange` handlers.
*(The React props should stay consistent anyway)*

E.g:

```
props: {
    onChange: MultiSelectDispatcher | SelectDispatcher,
    ...
}
```

And also use a type guard, like:

```
// Note: This type guard works, but is not inherently type safe.
const guardMultiSelectOnChange = ( onChange: unknown, multiSelect: boolean ): onChange is MultiSelectDispatcher => {
    return multiSelect;
}

if( guardMultiSelectOnChange( onChange, isMultiSelect )) {
    onChange({ answers, isHeadless });
} else {
    onChange({ answers, displayMode });
}
```

### Still problems ...

My last type guard `guardMultiSelectOnChange` makes another problem obvious:

We always assumed that the `onChange` function is the correct one *if* `isMultiSelect` is one or the other.
But nothing prevents someone to pass `isMultiSelect: false` and the `MultiSelectDispatcher`.

It would be better to type guard the function signature itself, instead of just stating `onChange is MultiSelectDispatcher` if
some other property (`isMultiSelect`) has some value.

But that will be a somewhat larger refactoring, outside the scope of this question, I guess.

Comment: The problem was in the old typescript version that doesn't support https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions as @jcalz noticed in the comments section.

Comment: Ok, I agree, then it will work now, and also type guards seem to be deprecated _(I'm not familiar with the new best practices yet)_. I suppose my "Still problems" section still applies, doesn't it ?